# use nested class without instance

Tags: python

I am working on python web application using `dash`.In a module,Earlier all were individual variables inside my `Utils` class, For eg:

```
class Utils:
   port = some_port
   address = f"some_domain:some_port"
   gui_docs = f"{some_domain}/docs"
   gui_pgadmin = f"{some_domain}/pgadmin4"
   gui_flower = f"{some_domain}/flower"
   and many more
```

This is currently working and accessing it in other modules, For eg:

```
Utils.gui_docs
etc
```

As the application is getting evolved, more variables are getting added and feels, I am losing track for the variables. So I am trying to refactor it. This is my approach and I am getting error as

```
unable to access nested class inside other nested class.
```

```
class Utils:

    class WebAddress:
        """Contain web address attributes."""

        _port: int = 80

        DOMAIN: str = f"http://some_domain:{_port}"
        

    class GUI:
        """Contain GUI attributes."""

        FLOWER_CELERY = html.A("Celery", href=f"{WebAddress.DOMAIN}/flower/")
        PGADMIN_POSTGRES = html.A("Postgres", href=f"{WebAddress.DOMAIN}/pgadmin4/")
        SRC_DOCS = html.A("Documentation", href=f"{WebAddress.DOMAIN}/docs/")
        
     --->  # Here, I am unable to access the `WebAddress.DOMAIN` inside `GUI` class
```

Now, I will access them in other modules as

```
Utils.GUI.FLOWER_CELERY
```

1. What I am missing?
2. Any other better way to approach such scenario?

Comment: I think `WebAddress.DOMAIN` needs to be `Utils.WebAddress.DOMAIN`.

Comment: Unless you have other top-level classes in the same file, it might make sense to get rid of the `Utils` class, and keep only the inner classes as module-level objects. The module can serve as the top-level container.

Comment: Hi 0x5453, Thanks. I did tried that earlier but failed with same error.

Comment: Hi Blckknght, Thanks. As you suggested I took those nested classes outside of `Utils` class and Now inside `Utils` class I can access them as `composition`. Still doubt, Aren't those nested classes are `class variables` of `Utils` class? so we can access them by class name.

Comment: What **exactly** is the error you are getting?

Comment: "# Here, I am unable to access the `WebAddress.DOMAIN` inside `GUI` class" because class bodies aren't enclosing scopes

Comment: @0x5453 that won't work because `Utils` doesn't exist yet when `class GUI` is being executed (`Utils` itself is in the process of being executed!)

Comment: Anyway, yeah, this really isn't what classes are for. Why not just using a `types.SimpleNamespace`?

Comment: Hi juanpa, Thanks. I was not aware of this `types.SimpleNamespace`. I will check this out.